# How to prevent a CPT's slug and page slug from conflicting with each other?

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, slug

I have a custom post type made and it uses `'slug' => 'treatments’`. I also have a page made in the back-end that uses `/treatments/`, but because I have `'has_archive' => false` the page loads fine. The issue I’m having is once I make another page a child of `/treatments/` it 404s. Would I need to adjust stuff in my registered custom post type to make it work?

The only solution I can think of is to remove the parent on the child page or changing the slug in my custom post type, neither I would like to do.

What can I do to retain both the cpt slug and page slug and have things work magically?

Comment: I'm not sure I would WANT to do that.  It Makes a user see inconsistency in the site.  Why would something other than your CPT treatments be after the treatments/ slug?  If you need to though use a redirect.